# ImportError: cannot import name force_text

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have installed Python 2.7 and Django 1.4 in my CentOS machine and installed all dependencies for my existing project. When I run `python manage.py runserver`, I am getting the following traceback in my console

```
[root@localhost bv]# python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x8ddd7ec>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from debug_toolbar.toolbar.loader import load_panel_classes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/toolbar/loader.py", line 12, in <module>
    from debug_toolbar.utils.settings import CONFIG
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/utils/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import force_text
ImportError: cannot import name force_text
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.force_text)

> New in Django 1.5.

Comment: It's not recommended to run applications as the "root" User :/

Comment: You don't appear to be up to date on your installation of django-debug-toolbar (the current version has no `utils/__init__.py`, just a `utils.py`). Can you send your version info or try updating to latest? According to the [readme](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar), it supports Django ≥ 1.4.2 and Python ≥ 2.6.5.

Comment: @jonafato djnago 1.4 is installed,so what django-debug-toolbar version should i install.If i install django-debug-toolbar using pip or yum it is installing the latest version along with django1.6,which is not supported by satchmo. Please help me in solve this.

Comment: @user2681579 You should be able to install the latest version of django-debug-toolbar as long as your django version is > 1.4.2 (you can see this using `python -c "import django; print django.VERSION"`) using `pip install django-debug-toolbar --upgrade`.

Comment: @jonafato if i run this command using pip install django-debug-toolbar --upgrade it is installing django1.6 also.I want to install django 1.4.2 and the debug-toolbar for that version.Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: @user2681579 `pip install django==1.4.2 django-debug-toolbar==0.11.0`. You should probably run `pip uninstall django django-debug-toolbar` first to remove existing versions.

Answer (score 6):

Upgrade to the latest Django 1.4 (as of 07-08-2014 - the "1.4.13").

I see that they have added a shortcut (`force_text`) in the `django.utils.encoding` module:  https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/utils/encoding.py

Note, that the shortcut wasn't there in the initial 1.4 version (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/utils/encoding.py) and was only added in 1.4.2 (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/utils/encoding.py).

As stated in the docs of `django-debug-toolbar`, current version (as of 07-08-2014 - the "1.2.1") works fine on Django 1.4 to 1.7.

Thus, make sure you use latest version of `Django` 1.4.x and `django-debug-toolbar`.

Comment: when I import it manually in the command-line than I get the following:
>>> import django as dj
>>> print(dj.__version__)
4.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I solved it by installing Django with LTS. In this case ***pip install Django==3.2***

Check https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ for reference

Comment: thank your. it help me too. I do not know what is wrong with the latest django version.

Comment: @zaman glad it solved your issue