# import error 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm implementing a graphql solution using python, graphene and django and I'm getting the following import error:

```
Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'

"/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/utils.py", line 6, in <module> from django.utils.encoding import force_text
```

I'm not sure about the versions and whether I need to import an additional module.
My requirements.txt is like:

```
graphene>=2.1,<3
graphene-django>=2.1,<3
graphql-core>=2.1,<3
graphql-relay==2.0.1
django-filter>=2
```

Has someone had a similar problem and can look at the versions that I use?
Thanks

Comment: This post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/25178353/14457833

Comment: What django version you are using?

Comment: thanks I have seen this post as well. However its not fully clear to me. Mainly I need graphene_django. Do I need to downgrade the django core?

Comment: in graphene_django.utils.utils.py the line 6 is the problem: from django.utils.encoding import force_text as django is not in my requirements.txt it is not clear to me, which version can avoid this error. 
print(django.__version__) returns 4.0

Comment: Exact same error when I ignored package version numbers doing the tutorial from https://www.howtographql.com/ . +1 thanks for asking before me :)

Answer (score 86):

in django 4.0 we dont have `force_text`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding

instead change `force_text` to `force_str`

linux:

YOUR_VENV/lib/PYTHON_VERSION/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/utils.py

windows:

YOUR_VENV/lib/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/utils.py

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
```

to

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_str
```

and

```
def _camelize_django_str(s):
    if isinstance(s, Promise):
        s = force_text(s)
    return to_camel_case(s) if isinstance(s, six.string_types) else s
```

to

```
def _camelize_django_str(s):
    if isinstance(s, Promise):
        s = force_str(s)
    return to_camel_case(s) if isinstance(s, six.string_types) else s
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I can change it locally in the venv, however this is not a valid solution as I'm deploying to the cloud and the venv will be created on the target.

Comment: you can also edit on remote server

Answer (score 32):

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70389991/1639453) given by @Osman.

The problem seems to be occuring with Django-4. Till the [PR](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/pull/1275) gets merged, probably this monkeypatching might work (not tested in prod):

```
import django
from django.utils.encoding import force_str
django.utils.encoding.force_text = force_str
```

Put this in entryfile. I kept it in settings.py for time being.

Comment: what is this entryfile file?

Comment: entryfile (entrypoint) could be anything which invokes first in order to spun the entire application. In my case, I used settings.py. Idea is to change the imported object before it's called by anything else.

Comment: This is a hacky but cleaner workaround! Cleaner because upgrading `graphene_django` will not need any subsequent change. Hacky because changing class attributes at run-time is considered a hack.

Comment: this works well, i used those lines in settings.py

Comment: today this hack didn't work anymore. I had to replace all `force_text` by `force_str`

Answer (score 14):

In Django version 4> just paste this snippet to your settinsg.py. Preferably on the top

```
    import django
    from django.utils.encoding import force_str
    django.utils.encoding.force_text = force_str
```

Answer (score 12):

`force_text` is removed from **Django 4.0** but the old version of **graphene_django** still uses `force_text` in `utils.py`. *You can see [Features removed in 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0).

So, upgrading `graphene-django` will solve the error easily:

```
pip install graphene-django --upgrade
```

Or, replace `force_text` with `force_str` as shown below:

```py
# "utils.py"

# from django.utils.encoding import force_text # Line 6
from django.utils.encoding import force_str # Line 6

# s = force_text(s) # Line 29
s = force_str(s) # Line 29
```

These are the paths to `utils.py` for **Linux** and **Windows**:

**Linux:**

> <your_venv>/lib/<python_version>/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/utils.py

**Windows:**

> <your_venv>/lib/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/utils.py

Answer (score 2):

adding the following to the requirements.txt solved it:

```
django<=3
```

Comment: Careful if you are using this method because you might not get the latest version of Django 3. You might get the 3.0 version which has many vulnerabilities. Instead, create a file `requirements.in` with `Django<4` for example. Then do `pip install pip-compile` and then `pip-compile`. This will regenerated requirements.txt with dependencies, and finally `pip-compile --upgrade` to get the latest versions of packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can install graphene-django version 3.0.0b7
run the following command in your terminal:

```sh
pip install graphene-django==3.0.0b7
```

It's beta version, but i don't know why graphene-django 2.15 does'nt work, when patch note said they fixed issue since 2.8.1 version.

Thank's to @Behoston from this Github issue for this solution

Answer (score 0):

I have been running into a similar issue whereby including `"graphql_jwt.refresh_token.apps.RefreshTokenConfig"` in `INSTALLED_APPS` leads to the following import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'
```

I added this at the top of settings.py:

```
import django
from django.utils.encoding import force_str
django.utils.encoding.force_text = force_str
```

And was greeted with this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation'
```

Where I then added the following to the top of settings.py:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy
django.utils.translation.ugettext = gettext
django.utils.translation.ugettext_lazy = gettext_lazy
```

And delightfully resolved this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'providing_args'
```

Django version 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

For people that want a release independent version:

```
try:
    from django.utils.encoding import force_text
except:
    from django.utils.encoding import force_str as force_text
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still finding trouble, I got this error by compressor dependency.
So I just did `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt`. In my case it was a requirements.txt file, but this works for all dependencies. Just upgrade them to fix the code, if it's not an error from your code.