# Adding 'graphene_django' in INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'graphene_django' ] of the settings.py file makes the django project to crush

Tags: python, django

Adding 'graphene_django' in INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'graphene_django' ] makes the django project makes the server to crush

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'graphene_django',
    "ingredients",
]
```

Here is the error that appears

```
 from django.utils.encoding import force_text
ImportError: cannot import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import error 'force\_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382084/import-error-force-text-from-django-utils-encoding)

Comment: No, it does not answer to my question at all.  I have no where in the code that I am using 'force_text'. So changing ```force_text```  to ```force_str```, won't work for me (as that solution suggests)

Comment: Just downgrade Django to version 3.X until all the packages you use have been updated for version 4

Comment: Yes, that worked(it removed the error), thank you. @IainShelvington

Answer (score 0):

For django version 4.x

**For Windows**
Go to project - `YOUR_ENV/lib/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/utils.py`

Find and replace - `"force_text"` to `"force_str"`

This worked for me.