# ImportError: cannot import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'

Tags: django, graphql, django-authentication, graphene-django, django-rest-framework-jwt

```
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ExtendUser(AbstractUser):
email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)
EMAIL_FIELD = 'email
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'graphene_django',
'graphql_auth',
"graphql_jwt.refresh_token.apps.RefreshTokenConfig",

'user',
```

]

I'm working on a Django GraphQL-JWT project and everything seems working until I `pip install django-graphql-auth` and then add `graphene_django` in my INSTALLED APPS that's when I get this error when I try `python manage.py migrate` or runserver.

[image]

Comment: Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382084/import-error-force-text-from-django-utils-encoding0

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby the error is gone but then comes with another error `cannot import name 'ugettext' from 'django.utils.translation'`.

Comment: This has been removed as well, search google to get the equivalent answer from stackoverflow

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry about that but the problem has nothing to do with my code cos I have little code. that's a user model code. This problem was about two different packages  not working together. it's working now because  I had to downgrade to django==3.*.

Answer (score 1):

Dowgrading to older version of Django is not a good solution. The packages you are using are not supporting Django 4 hence the issues. You should do one of the following:

- Check other alternative packages that do support Django 4. I believe you can use [Simple JWT](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-simplejwt/) which does support Django 4.
- If you don't want to use other package you can just update the existing package codebase by replacing `ugettext` to `gettext` and `force_text` to `force_str` as these have been updated in newer version of django.